# functor with overloaded () operator in map - only evaluate on demand

Tags: c++, dictionary, functor

I'd like to have one functor object with overloaded `() operator` and store one of each of these overloaded versions in a map. This way i could keep my logic in one class, here's a small code of what iam trying to accomplish:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class functor{
public:
    void operator()(int i){
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    void operator()(string s){
        cout << s << endl;
    }
    void operator()(int i, int j){
        cout << i+j << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    // i know i should put something here thats not "functor" 
    // but i have no idea what. 
    map<int,functor> hTable;

    // is there a way to add elements into a table somehow like this...
    hTable[0] = functor()(2);
    hTable[1] = functor()("foo and bar are overrated, boo.");
    hTable[2] = functor()(2,3);

    // and fire the function in the table simply like this?
    hTable[0];

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (The problem with `functor()(..)` is that it evaluates immediately.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to "bind" certain parameters to a function?  Certainly!

```
#include <functional>
int main(){
    // A map of integers to functions
    //each function takes no parameters () and returns nothing (void)
    map<int,std::function<void()>> hTable;

    // add elements into a table like this...
    hTable[0] = std::bind(functor(), 2);
    hTable[1] = std::bind(functor(), "foo and bar are overrated, boo.");
    hTable[2] = std::bind(functor(), 2, 3);

    // and fire the function in the table simply like this
    hTable[0]();

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

See it live here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8042e98b19ccbf6b

Additionally, `std::function` and `std::bind` can work on functionoids(like yours), lambdas, function pointers, member functions... they're amazing.  `std::bind` also has placeholders which are awesome too:

```
double divide(int left, int right) {return (double)left/right;}

//brings _1 into the current scope
using std::placeholders; 
//bind the first input as the first parameter, bind 100 to the second parameter 
std::function<double(int)> percent = std::bind(divide, _1, 100); 
//the resulting function only has one input:
double half = percent(50);
```

Comment: One just must love Boost and `std::`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. This code works like a charm. And its short and fancy.